# Variable not picking up returned value from function

Tags: node.js, sails.js, mailgun

I'm trying to collect the of returned values of two functions, send-mail and sendsms, into a variable(var ordermessage). It picks up the returned value from send-sms just fine.

I'm using the mailgun api for send-mail, and ordermessage just picks up 'undefined'. But send-mail keeps running.

I've tried `await mailgun.messages().send(...)`
I've tried `const myvar = await mailgun.messages().send(...)`
and also `let myvar = await mailgun.messages().send...`

Nada.

I tried using a function that had the api call as a callback. Still got undefined. The email and sms both get sent, but I need the reply from the email server. I'm using Mailgun trial so I need to return a response.

send-mail.js

```
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY, domain: process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN});
  var processresponse = "\n";

  var data = {
    from: 'Zigy Demo Store <admin_demo@zigy.com>',
    to: email,
    subject: 'You have placed an order.',
    text: body
  };

  console.log("\n----------START EMAIL-------------\n");

mailgun.messages()
  .send(data, function (error, body) {
    console.log("\nFinally running MAILGUN. Return body is\n", body);
    if (body == undefined || body == false) { 
      console.log("Got nothing from server.");
    } else {
      processresponse += body.message;
      console.log("***********************Gotten reply from Mailgun server.*******************************\n", processresponse);
    }
  });
```

OrderController function

```
module.exports = {
    neworder: async function(req, res) {
        var sendemail = require('./send-mail');
        var sendtext = require('./send-sms');

        var orderdetails = 'New order created at '+ new Date() + '\nItem  ---> Price'; //Message that will be sent to users.
        var item;
        var printcart = await Shoppingcart.findOne({
            where: {
                id: req.body.cart,
                owner: req.body.user
            }
        }).populate('product');
        var ordermessage = '';

        for (items in printcart.product) {
            item = printcart.product[items];
            orderdetails += '\n' + item.name + ' ---> ' + item.price;
        }
        console.log(orderdetails);
        //to get email addr and phone number
        phone = req.body.phone; 
        var email = req.body.email;

        var user = await User.findOne({id:printcart.owner});

        ordermessage += await sendemail(email, orderdetails); 
        console.log("\nAfter email, the message is ", ordermessage);

        ordermessage += await sendtext(phone, orderdetails);
        console.log("\nAfter text, Printing order message to be returned to browser ", ordermessage);

        console.log("Final message ", ordermessage);

        res.send(ordermessage);
    }
};
```

Terminal

```
----------START EMAIL-------------

Calling test function

After email, the message is  


Finally running MAILGUN. Return body is
 { id:
   '<20190222062410.1.FD7A4868FA0ADF5E@sandbox612cf746219c46ad93d5dc588f9341ff.mailgun.org>',
  message: 'Queued. Thank you.' }
***********************Gotten reply from Mailgun server.*******************************

Queued. Thank you.
Checking list of verified numbers...
Found the phonenumber!
You will receive an SMS message with your order details soon.

After text, Printing order message to be returned to browser  
You will receive an SMS message with your order details soon.
Final message  
You will receive an SMS message with your order details soon.
SM9bc04208f9354834a153fb1ffd7dc8bb
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I called res.write from inside send-mail.js and send-sms.js instead and got rid of the variable ordermessage.

Comment: Looks like you missed the return statement i guess... Something like this: `..send(data, (error, body) => { return body; })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess: I think the `mailgun.messages().send(...)` method doesn't return anything as it uses a classic callback. So you will always get `undefined` from it.

But you get the result from the body parameter in the callback. You could use [Promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to transform the callback into a promise style method.

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

const messages = mailgun.messages();

const sendPromisified = util.promisify(messages.send());
sendPromisified(data).then((body) => {
  // Do something with `body`
}).catch((error) => {
  // Handle mailgun error
});

// Async / await style
try {
   const mailBody = await sendPromisified(data);
} catch (err) {
   // handle mailgun error `err`
}
```